# Inner class issue when using onclicklistener

Tags: android, inner-classes

I keep getting repeated issues with: variable is accessed from within inner class
every time i want to use an object etc from an onclicklistener etc.

I know the problem is that its not set to final, but if i set to final im not able to do anything to it before pressing the onclicklistener button...

Example i have an EditText field, which is filled with getText from an object, then i want to press an apply button and the object with the new text from the textfield.

This doesnt work when the object need to be final for the "inner class" to use it.

How do i best handle this? i keep running into this bloody phenonemon...

```
public class EditPicture extends Activity{

private EditText text;
private Button applyBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID itemID = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("itemUUID");
    PictureItem pi = new PictureItem("","");

    final ArrayList<PictureItem> tempArray = PictureTalkFragment.array;
    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++){
        if(itemID.equals(tempArray.get(i).getId())){
            pi = tempArray.get(i);
            tempArray.remove(i);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.picturetalk_edit_pic);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    text.setText(pi.getTitle());
    applyBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.applyChangeBtn);
    applyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tempArray.add(pi);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: define you variable `tempArray` out of `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the inner class issues. Know from now on to have such functions OUTSIDE of those Override methods:) Still have issues with getting the Arraylist from the other class though. Guessing im calling on an PictureTalkFragment which isnt created (my class doesnt know the instance). and im to noob to know how to handle it.

Comment: please accept my answer then :)
I didn't get your other problem. ask another question for that for further helps.

Comment: Thumbsup :) will create new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define `tempArray` variable outside of `onCreate` method.

```
public class EditPicture extends Activity{

private EditText text;
private Button applyBtn;

ArrayList<PictureItem> tempArray

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID itemID = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("itemUUID");
    PictureItem pi = new PictureItem("","");

    tempArray = PictureTalkFragment.array;

    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++){
        if(itemID.equals(tempArray.get(i).getId())){
            pi = tempArray.get(i);
            tempArray.remove(i);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.picturetalk_edit_pic);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    text.setText(pi.getTitle());
    applyBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.applyChangeBtn);
    applyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tempArray.add(pi);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add th picture to a temporary array which is not accesible when you click on it. I think that you can do something like this to define the array outside the inCreate function.

```
public class EditPicture extends Activity{

private EditText text;
private Button applyBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID itemID = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("itemUUID");
    PictureItem pi = new PictureItem("","");

    final ArrayList<PictureItem> tempArray = PictureTalkFragment.array;
    for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.size(); i++){
        if(itemID.equals(tempArray.get(i).getId())){
            pi = tempArray.get(i);
            tempArray.remove(i);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.picturetalk_edit_pic);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    text.setText(pi.getTitle());
    applyBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.applyChangeBtn);
    applyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(PictureTalkFragment.array != null){
               PictureTalkFragment.array.add(pi);
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue with inner class by cleaning up my oncreate and moving all those functions out like the above suggested. Dunno of it works completely yet cause im having problems with nullpoint on ArrayList<PictureItem> tempArray = PictureTalkFragment.array; I added an getter and setter method in the other class, and even made the arraylist public. But it keep ending with nullpoint exception. Basiclly im calling an arraylist from a class that this class doesnt know the instance of. But im just to noob to understand how/where i should get the reference to the allread created instance.

Comment: For this reason, when you are not sure that your array is not null, make an if to avoid the exception like in my code.
Check that your static element array in PictureTalkFragment is not null when you give it to EditPicture.